# Issue with constructor Circle in class Circle javafx.scene.shape.*;

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create a simple circle from the standard javafx.scene.shape. * Class. When I try to compile the program, I get the following error message. I'm using Java 8.291!
I try to create a circle with one argument but the error messages tells me that no argument is expected.

> ```
> test2.java:33: error: constructor Circle in class Circle cannot be applied to given types;
>            Circle circleA = new Circle(20);
>                             ^
> **required: no arguments
> found: int**
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
> test2.java:35: error: no suitable method found for addAll(Circle)
>            rootNode.getChildren().addAll(circleA);
>                                  ^
> method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends Node>) is not applicable
>  (argument mismatch; Circle cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Node>)
> method List.addAll(Collection<? extends Node>) is not applicable
>  (argument mismatch; Circle cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Node>)
> method ObservableList.addAll(Node...) is not applicable
>  (varargs mismatch; Circle cannot be converted to Node)
> Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
> 2 errors
> ```

```java
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.transform.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;

public class test2 extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        // Start the JavaFX application by calling launch().
        launch(args);
    }

    // Override the start() method.
    public void start(Stage myStage){
        myStage.setTitle("Transformer");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(40, 40);
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 500, 200);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
        Circle circleA = new Circle(20);
        rootNode.getChildren().addAll(circleA);
        myStage.show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles and runs without errors for me. Are you sure you copied your exact code to your post?

Comment: My guess is an import issue.

Comment: Thanks for checking it. It seems I have a serious issues with my Java environment on my computer. But the good news is, my code is correct :)